# Get Specific substrings from strings in JAVA

Tags: java, substring

I have strings of the format `"{-LS4kp5hQc6Uodf={name=random, suggestion=OK, id=kj61sCceDs34Nr1}}"`. Here I want to take the name substring (here `"random"`) and suggestion substring (here `"OK"`) to 2 different string. How to do that?

P.S.- the format of all strings are similar.

Comment: Why don't use use JSON? You had better use JSON and use Gson library to parse. 
{"-LS4kp5hQc6Uodf": {"name": "random", "suggestion": "OK", "id": "kj61sCceDs34Nr1"}}
Change like this and use JSON.

Comment: Please describe in a little detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions if you don't want to use json.

```
String data = "{-LS4kp5hQc6Uodf={name=random, suggestion=OK, id=kj61sCceDs34Nr1}}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=(.*),.*suggestion=(.*),");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //name value
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));//suggestion value
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful!